# Performing data lookup in excel

Tags: excel

Sorry i'm still new with excel and still learning on use excel to lookup data. I would like to accomplish the following and was hoping that someone would be able to help me with the formula.

i have the following data in Sheet1.
[image: Sheet1]

On Sheet2 i would like to lookup the data from Sheet1 and output it as below
[image: Sheet2]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the heart of your question is how you get information from a sheet outside of your primary sheet. In order to pull data from another sheet you would want to put the sheet name where a reference would be followed by an exclamation point.

So in this case you want information from "Sheet1" referenced in "Sheet2". Let's say you want the first hostname from Sheet1 in Sheet2 cell A1. You would input the following into A1 of Sheet2:

```
=Sheet1!A2
```

Cell A1 would then populate with "Hostname1" from your image examples.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. What i would like to do is have the hostname repeat itself times by the number port which is listed. Once like in the above example the Node have 2 ports so it would Hostname1 would repeat itself 2 times before starting with Hostname2. If Node has 3 port then i t would repeat itself 3 times before going on to the next Host. If Node2 is available with the number of ports it will keep on repeating before going to the next host.